# How to prefilter a list of dicts that I want to insert into a sql table where each dict has an extra column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 connector, and I would like to insert a list of dicts into the sql table.
However, this list of dicts may have an extra column that isn't part of the sql table schema.

Obviously, I can pre-filter the list of dicts to remove this column prior to using `executemany`, and that's what I'm currently doing. Is there a native way for sqlite3 to handle this filtering directly for me? If I just try to insert the dicts without filtering, it'll fail and say I provided more columns than necessary.

Comment: actually it works but every `dict` should contain **all** attributes specified in the SQL-`insert` statement. Could you add a minimal working example showing the issue?

Comment: @cards wow, it seems my premise was wrong. I could've sworn I've gotten an error like "sql schema has 80 columns, 81 provided" in the past, but I must have imagined it. i just tested it and it works

Answer (score 0):

When adding values into a table in `sqlite3` the keys of the dictionaries must correspond (at least) to all attribute of the SQL-`insert` statement, all others keys of the dictionaries are automatically omitted.

Here an example

```py
import sqlite3


data = (
    {"name": "C", "year": 1972},
    {'name': "XYZ", 'year': 1999, 'gender': "male"} # <- extra "attribute"
)

with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    # create table
    cur = con.execute("CREATE TABLE lang(name, first_appeared)")

    # populate table
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO lang VALUES(:name, :year)", data)

    # perform query
    rows = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM lang")

    # format output
    apply_template = "{:<10}| {:4}".format

    # display output
    for row in rows:
        print(apply_template(*row))
```

Output

```
C         | 1972
XYZ       | 1999  # <- extra key, "gender",  is automatically omitted
```

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-adapt-custom-python-types-to-sqlite-values

How to register adapter callables
The other possibility is to create a function that converts the Python object to an SQLite-compatible type. This function can then be registered using register_adapter().

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

def adapt_point(point):
    return f"{point.x};{point.y}"

sqlite3.register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT ?", (Point(1.0, 2.5),))
print(cur.fetchone()[0])
```